# Passing an array to an MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

I would like to pass an array of IDs to a controller. Originally I was adding each ID in the query string like so:

http://localhost:4000/customers/active?customerId=1&customerId=2&customerId=3

Then on the controller side I had a method that would accept the array like this:

```
GetCustomers([FromQuery] int[] ids)
{
   ...
}
```

This was working well but there are a few situations where there are so many `customerIds` in the array that the query string became too long so I had to modify the way that the query was being passed to this:

http://localhost:4000/customers/active?customerIds=1,2,3

I got the solution working by changing `GetCustomers` params to accept a string instead of an int array and then parsed the `customerIds` out in the controller (using `.Split(',')`)

I feel like it was cleaner to pass an array directly instead of having to modify the string on the server side. Is there a way to achieve this given the way the `customerIds` are now being passed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768245/web-api-passing-array-of-integers-to-action-method/37768858#37768858

Comment: [Model binding comma separated query string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9584573/3110834)

Comment: Is the action a POST or GET?

Comment: @Nkosi it's a GET

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass an array of integers to ASP.NET Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api)

Answer (score 2):

**1.** USE POST

**2.** USE AJAX & SEND DATA AS JSON

```
 $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/Home/GetCustomers",
           data : { stringOfCustomerIds : JSON.stringify(arrCustomerIds)},
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (response) {
                 //do something with the response
           }
```

& on the controller side

```
public JsonResult GetCustomers(string stringOfCustomerIds )
{
     JObject CustomerIdsJson = JObject.Parse(listOfCustomerIds );

       foreach (JProperty property in CustomerIdsJson .Properties())
       {
           Console.WriteLine(property.ID+ " - " + property.Value);
       }

      return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  

}
```

Comment: If you going to do a POST, then it would be just `data : JSON.stringify({ stringOfCustomerIds : arrCustomerIds }),` with `contentType: 'application/json'` and the method would be `public JsonResult GetCustomers(int[] stringOfCustomerIds)` (let the `ModelBinder` do its work)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your use of the `[FromQuery]` attribute, I can tell that you are using .NET Core (which this only applies to). `[FromQuery]` has no way of knowing which part of the query string you want to map to the parameter, so you have to provide a `Name` parameter like this:

`[FromQuery(Name ="ids")]`

The `Name` parameter can have whatever value you'd like. Just as long as your query matches the name you select. So for the example above:

`?ids=2&ids=3&ids=4` but if you were to formulate the attribute like

`[FromQuery(Name = "kittens")]` then you would need to make your query look like

`?kittens=2&kittens=3&kittens=4`

Following this methodology you'll be able to see that your parameter is populated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the IDs as a JSON object in the body of the message using a POST request on the front end and the `[FromBody]` tag on the back end controller. This way your url will simply look like this: `http://localhost:4000/customers/active` no matter how many IDs are present in the body of the message. It also saves you the hassle of extracting and pushing each parameter into a new array element.